# Search for same values in 2 lists but only once if duplicate

Tags: python, list, duplicates

```
lst1 = [0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 13.0]
lst2 = [4.,  8.]
[i for i, j in enumerate(lst1) if j in lst2]
```

I will get a return of:

```
[4, 8, 9]
```

What I want to achieve is that I would want a return of:

```
[4, 8]
```

because `8.0` is repeated in `lst1`, I only want that once. What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: You mean it will return `[4, 8, 8]`.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I can readily think of is, maintain a set of already seen numbers and if the number is not in the already `seen` set then add the `index` to the `result` and the number to the `seen` set.

```
result, seen = [], set()
for index, item in enumerate(lst1):
    if item not in seen and item in lst2:
        result.append(index)
        seen.add(item)
print(result)
# [4, 8]
```

**Note 1:** We use a `set` for maintaining the `seen` items, because the lookups will be very fast (constant time lookup)

**Note 2:** If your `lst2` is also going to be a long list, then better convert that also a set, so that `item in lst2` lookup will also happen in constant time. So the actual code becomes,

```
result, seen, set2 = [], set(), set(lst2)
for index, item in enumerate(lst1):
    if item not in seen and item in set2:
        result.append(index)
        seen.add(item)
print(result)
# [4, 8]
```

This will give better performance than the first version, if the `lst2` is going to be a lengthy one.

An alternate solution inspired by DSM's solution is, building a reverse index dictionary, like this

```
>>> reverse_indexes = {lst1[i]: i for index in xrange(len(lst1) - 1, -1, -1)}
```

Then we can simply do the lookup like this

```
>>> [reverse_indexes[item] for item in lst2 if item in reverse_indexes]
[4, 8]
```

Comment: This is way overly complicated.

Comment: And why is that important? Did OP express any kind of concern for runtime?

Comment: Because this is python and the zen of python states that simple is better than complex?

Comment: `O(n)` is better than `O(n²)` as the latter is more complex, Q.E.D.

Comment: Nope, it is more like `O(nm)`

Comment: Runtime is not the only factor when talking about simplicity/complexity of code.

Comment: Have you every heard the phrase: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"? http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: thefourtheye's solution is `O(n+m)`

Comment: Both solutions have the same running time of `O(nm)`. The other just iterates `lst1` one extra time.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way. This is also going to iterate only once over each list.

```
>>> def first_indices(lst1, lst2):
...     s = set(lst2)
...     l = []  
...     for i, element in enumerate(lst1):
...         try:
...             s.remove(element)
...             l.append(i)
...         except KeyError:
...             pass
...     return l
... 
>>> first_indices(lst1, lst2)
[4, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit ugly but it is using a list comprehension. I am abusing the fact that `set.discard` returns `None`. Basically we make a `set` of `lst2`; here we call it `needles` as we're searching needles in haystack. As soon as we find a value in the *haystack* `lst1` that is also in `needles`, we discard that value from the set of needles to find, and add its index to the resulting list.

```
needles = set(lst2)
results = [needles.discard(v) or i 
           for i, v in enumerate(lst1) if v in needles]
```

Comment: If you are going to mutate inside a list comprehension, might as well just use a single set.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1 = [0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 13.0]
lst2 = [4.0, 8.0]
lst = []
for i in lst2:
    if i in lst1: # checks if the element i occurs in lst1
        lst.append(lst1.index(i))
print(lst)
```

The result is `[4, 8]`

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1 = [0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 13.0]
lst2 = [ 4.,  8.]

result = set()
for idx, i in enumerate(lst1):
    if i in lst2:
        result.update([i])

# prints [4,8]           
print list(result)
```

Hi^^ in the above example, I use `list(set(list_example))` method to append a number without duplicates to a list.

`set()` works as follow: you declare the set and then use `update()` to update the set without duplicates.

```
a = set()
a.update([2])
a.update([3])
a.update([2])

print list(a) # prints [2,3]
```

**note:** assume that the list is unordered due to the nature of `set`

Good luck!~ :)

Comment: result is a set, so it is unordered, could print 8, 4, etc.

Comment: Your inner `for` loop is better written as: `if i in lst2: result.add(i)`

Comment: Thank you~! I have changed my code addressing your comment.

Comment: Ah but I just noticed another problem with the code: the question was about indices - the result was supposed to contain only indices of the elements

Answer (score 0):

`list.index(x)` will return the index of the first occurrence of the element in the list, so you can do:

```
[lst1.index(elem) for elem in lst2 if elem in lst1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `tmp` list which save selected elements i.e. elements are present in the both lists.

Demo:

```
>>> lst1 = [0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 13.0]
>>> lst2 = [ 4.0,  8.0]
>>> tmp = []
>>> result = []
>>> for i, j in enumerate(lst1):
...    if j in lst2 and j not in tmp:
...      result.append(i)
...      tmp.append(j)
... 
>>> print result
[4, 8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))  # Sets Intersection Concept
```

Output:
   [8, 4]

```
common = list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))
print "Common Items = ", common
for i in common:
    print lst1.index(i)  # It won't spit exception as we looking for already present item
```

Comment: lst1.index(i)  will return the index of first match